# fill html dropdown with php array

Tags: php, html

I am trying to fill an html dropdown with a php array. Currently, my code creates an empty dropdown and then prints the array on the screen under the dropdown. Below is the html.

```
          <label for="column1">Variable for Column 1: </label>
          <br>
          <form>
          <select name="cols1" id="cols1">
            <?php
            include 'hi2.php';
            $vars = getVars();
            foreach($vars as $item){
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo strtolower($item); ?>"><?php echo $item; ?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
          </select>
            </form>
```

This is what is returned from hi2.php

```
function getVars() {
$toReturn = array();
    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($ret)) 
    {
        $count = count($row);
        $y = 0;
        while ($y < $count)
        {
        
            $c_row = current($row);
        array_push($toReturn, $c_row);

        next($row);
            $y = $y + 1;
        }
    
        $i = $i + 1;
    }
return($toReturn);
```

When replacing the contents of the `foreach` loop to `var_dump($vars); die();`
This is the output of the array being printed under the dropdown after inspecting element in the browser

```
<form>
          <select name="cols1" id="cols1">
                

</select>array(22) {
  [0]=&gt;
  string(9) "westasian"
  [1]=&gt;
  string(15) "populationtotal"
  [2]=&gt;
  string(17) "population15total"
  [3]=&gt;
  string(14) "dwellingstotal"
  [4]=&gt;
  string(20) "averagedwellingvalue"
  [5]=&gt;
  string(22) "averagehouseholdincome"
  [6]=&gt;
  string(16) "populationage014"
  [7]=&gt;
  string(17) "populationage2534"
  [8]=&gt;
  string(17) "populationage3544"
  [9]=&gt;
  string(17) "populationage5564"
  [10]=&gt;
  string(15) "populationage65"
  [11]=&gt;
  string(17) "populationage4554"
  [12]=&gt;
  string(17) "populationage1524"
  [13]=&gt;
  string(10) "southasian"
  [14]=&gt;
  string(7) "chinese"
  [15]=&gt;
  string(5) "black"
  [16]=&gt;
  string(8) "filipino"
  [17]=&gt;
  string(13) "latinamerican"
  [18]=&gt;
  string(14) "southeastasian"
  [19]=&gt;
  string(4) "arab"
  [20]=&gt;
  string(35) "coffeerestauranttimhortonsregularly"
  [21]=&gt;
  string(10) "postalcode"
}
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of the output/rendered PHP? Can you confirm what the value of `$item` is?

Comment: And what have you already tried to figure out why it does that?

Comment: What does `hi2.php` contain? It's not obvious from what you've shown why you'd get that kind of result.

Comment: edited question to add `hi2.php` and contents of `$item`

Comment: Your items are `<option ...>`, not just the value. So you're essentially trying to do `<option value="<option ...>"><option ...></option>` so the browser recognizes this as invalid and fixes it the best it can. Change your `foreach` to just `echo $item;` and it should work.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones I tried making the `foreach` loop `echo $item;` but it didn't fix it

Comment: Yes you do need the `<option>` tag. But look at your hi2.php code...it already generates an `<option>` tag. So `foreach($vars as $item){ echo $item; }` should be sufficient to output those ready-made tags.

Comment: You didn't show it fully so it's not 100% clear, but is what you're describing as the `hi2.php` code actually the inside of the `getVars()` function?

Comment: @ADyson yes the `hi2.php` code shown here is the return part of the `getVars()` function. `getVars()` is 165 lines in total so I tried to only show the relevant parts

Comment: Ok. Well did you understand what we're saying? You don't need to generate `<option` twice for the same data. WOUNDEDStevenJones' answer below should be the correct solution. If it's still not doing what you expected when you use that, you'll need to clarify what it _is_ outputting instead.

Comment: How can clarify what it is outputting?

Comment: The normal way you check what a web page looks like - i.e. by looking in your browser's View Source tool (or the element inspector in the browser's Developer Tools). if you're working with HTML and web pages, this should really be a familiar process.

Comment: inside of your `foreach` loop, add `var_dump($item); die()` and then inspect the HTML via developer tools in your browser to see what the value of `$item` is.

Comment: Side note: `return($toReturn);` should be `return $toReturn;`. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php for more info.

Comment: edited question to add output from inspect element

Comment: Are you sure your function definition is `function getVars() = {`? That's not a valid PHP function, it should be `function getVars() {`

Comment: I made an error while copying

Comment: https://3v4l.org/LIiuL is a demo that is fully functioning. Can you tell us more about the environment you're coding in? Do you have a virtual machine or a docker environment on localhost, or are you using an online editor of some sort, or something else? Based on the code that you have provided, this should be working as expected. So there has to be another missing piece.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem. When inspecting the page the format is like this `<form> <select name="cols1" id="cols1"></select>
<option value="westasian">westasian</option>`. ie the select is empty from some reason

Comment: OK but the code you've shown wouldn't produce that. So we can't tell you how to fix that, based on your current information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you're setting `$toReturn` to be a list of HTML options like:

```
[
  '<option value="test">Test</option>',
  '<option value="test2">Test2</option>',
  '<option value="test3">Test3</option>'
]
```

so in your `foreach` loop you only need to output the value - you don't need to output the `<option ...>` in HTML again. Change your first script to the following:

```
<form>
    <select name="cols1" id="cols1">
    <?php
        include 'hi2.php';
        $vars = getVars();
        foreach($vars as $item){
            echo $item;
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

*Note: technically in `hi2.php` you're not using `strtolower` on the value, so you'll probably want to add that.*

Another way to do this would be to edit your `hi2.php` script to instead return an array of *values* instead of the full HTML `option`.

```
$toReturn = array();
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($ret)) 
{
    $count = count($row);
    $y = 0;
    while ($y < $count)
    {
        $c_row = current($row);
        array_push($toReturn, $c_row);
   
        next($row);
        $y = $y + 1;
    }
    
    $i = $i + 1;
}
return $toReturn;
```

and then your `foreach` will work as expected using `$item`:

```
foreach($vars as $item){
    echo '<option value="' . strtolower($item) . '">' . $item . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: This solution still prints the contents of `$vars` under the dropdown, not inside it

Comment: Then try removing everything from this page and just do `<?php include 'hi2.php'; $vars = getVars(); var_dump($vars); die(); ?>` to see what the value of `$vars` is. I'm expecting it to be an array of strings like `'<option value="westasian">westasian</option>'`, but if that's not the case you'll need to let us know what that variable contains for us to guide you further.

Comment: Alternatively: `<?php include 'hi2.php'; $vars = getVars(); foreach($vars as $item) { var_dump($item); die(); } ?>` to view an individual item.